# How to link against libraries when using MingW and makefiles

Tags: c++, makefile, mingw, linker-errors, fltk

I downloaded and built FLTK (v. 1.3.4.1) using MingW and cmake which worked perfectly.
However I am having problems properly linking against FLTK resulting in lots of undefined references during linking. 
I do not have MSYS or any other shell for Windows installed which means using the 'fltk-config' script is not an option.

My knowledge of makefiles is rather sparse and the following has been built using the official documentation and various internet sources.

```
CC=g++
FLTK_INC=C:/frameworks/fltk-1.3.4-1
FLTK_BIN=C:/frameworks/fltk-1.3.4-1/bin
CFLAGS=-std=c++11 -Wall -I$(FLTK_INC) -v
LDFLAGS=-L$(FLTK_BIN)/lib
LDLIBS=-lfltk
EXT=cc
SOURCES=$(wildcard src/*.$(EXT))
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.$(EXT)=.o)
EXECUTABLE=hello

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.$(EXT).o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Is there something obviously wrong with this makefile or does the error lie somwehere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there something obviously wrong with this makefile or does the error lie somwehere else?

There are two things wrong with this makefile.

**Thing 1**

```
LDFLAGS=-L$(FLTK_BIN)/lib
LDLIBS=-lfltk
```

You have conventional GNU Make settings of linkage options:

```
LDFLAGS=-L$(FLTK_BIN)/lib
```

`$(LDFLAGS)` should occur at an appropriate position in your linkage
recipe to tell the linker that it should search in the directory
`$(FLTK_BIN)/lib` for any libraries specified with `-l` option (before
searching in its default directories).

```
LDLIBS=-lfltk
```

`$(LDLIBS)` should occur at an appropriate position in your linkage
recipe to tell the linker that it should link the shared library `libfltk.so`
or failing that, the static library `libfltk.a`. (On Windows, other extensions
are accepted).

Your linkage recipe:

```
$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@
```

has `$(LDFLAGS)` at an appropriate position but does not have `$(LDLIBS)`
anywhere. The linker therefore makes no attempt to link `libfltk`.
That very likely explains the undefined reference errors that you refer to,
although I can't be absolutely sure since you haven't revealed what they are.

The linkage recipe ought to be:

```
$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@ $(LDLIBS)
```

or more conventionally:

```
$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LDLIBS)
```

**Thing 2**

Your compile recipe:

```
.$(EXT).o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

is not actually a compile recipe. It is a compile-and-link recipe. `gcc/g++`
will always attempt to perform a linkage unless the commandline options
include `-c` ( = compile only). Since the recipe (correctly) does not include
any of the necessary linkage options - `$(LDFLAGS)`, `$(LDLIBS)` - the
premature attempted linkage fails and the build gets not further. The
commandline you have logged as producing the linkage errors:

```
g++ -std=c++14 -Wall -IC:/frameworks/fltk-1.3.4-1 -v src/hw.cc -o src/hw.o
```

is a substitution instance of your "compile" recipe:

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

and not of your linkage recipe:

```
$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@
```

To correct the compile recipe, make it:

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -c -o $@
```

[The GNU Make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html)
is good.

Comment: Followed your sensible advice but errors still abound. See [link](http://pastebin.com/2tr3CuRg)

Comment: @slimandstacked Please post the complete output of the failing make, not just the errors.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the makefile issues. There were a bunch of other libs needed for fltk to work properly but that is beyond the scope of this question.